# StackExchange: Some site icons broken on odata query results page

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, data-explorer, images

**Crosspost from https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/6610 as suggested**

Example:

http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/299/how-long-until-i-get-the-generalist-badge?UserId=1569

Note that SO/SU/SF/MSO are all broken, but Metas SU/SF and Web Apps are fine. Not sure if that's tied to my login, so here's a screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbWjE.png

The problem appears to be that while the working icons are

- http:// sstatic.net/superusermeta/**img**/favicon.ico

...the non-working ones are missing the img subdir in the path:

- http:// sstatic.net/superuser/favicon.ico

and I note that http://sstatic.net/superuser/img/favicon.ico does work.

Answer (score 1):

This is was fixed on the live site a while ago, and I have [corrected](https://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/source/detail?r=18837a9741f59e2c28bf3d153eec66a5b51b3bf3) the underlying script to mirror the fix.